# I am having trouble exporting the value of the URL in the promise to be supplied through out the express modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules

I have developing an app using ngrok!
I followed Phil post on how to setup ngrok with nodemon
link for the post : https://philna.sh/blog/2021/03/15/restart-app-not-tunnel-ngrok-nodemon/

I want to get the url received from the promise to be available in

> bin folder

through out the app server, so I can use inside my controllers.
How I can export the url value?

I tried to set an empty variable and export but it gives me undefined.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  console.error(
    "Do not use nodemon in production, run bin/www directly instead."
  );
  process.exitCode = 1;
  return;
    }

const ngrok = require("ngrok");
const nodemon = require("nodemon");
let tempUrl;


ngrok.connect({
    proto: "http",
    addr: "3000",
  })
  .then((url) => {
    tempUrl =url
    console.log("tempUrl insde ngrok fn",tempUrl)
    console.log(`ngrok tunnel opened at: ${url}`);
    console.log("Open the ngrok dashboard at: https://localhost:4040\n");

    nodemon({
      script: "./bin/www",
      exec: `NGROK_URL=${url} node`,
    }).on("start", () => {
      console.log("The application has started");
    }).on("restart", files => {
      console.group("Application restarted due to:")
      files.forEach(file => console.log(file));
      console.groupEnd();
    }).on("quit", () => {
      console.log("The application has quit, closing ngrok tunnel");
      ngrok.kill().then(() => process.exit(0));
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error opening ngrok tunnel: ", error);
    process.exitCode = 1;
  });

  console.log("tempUrl before module export",tempUrl)
```

Comment: You  mean using `process.env.NGROK_URL` inside the script that nodemon runs?

Comment: Hi Bergi,! Thank you! I don't realize that what exec does by assigning .env variable

Comment: Uh, that's what you wanted to achieve by running `NGROK_URL=${url} node`, no?

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I wanted! I didn't have that concept down , and your comment had me see it. I should have read the post expatiation till the end!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize that exec in nodemon is assigning a .env variable that can be used Thanks to Bergi.